# C# Bunifu UI System.NullReferenceException was unhandled

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, button, bunifu

I'm using Bunifu UI Framework,
everything was fine until I added an "Exit" button from the Bunifu UI which is bunifuFlatButton, I tried both this.Close(); and Close(); and with both I'm getting System.NullReferenceException was unhandled Error.

Button:

[image]

Error:

[image]

```
System.NullReferenceException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147467261
  Message=Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
  Source=Bunifu_UI_v1.5.3
  StackTrace:
       at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton.method_5()
       at Bunifu.Framework.UI.BunifuFlatButton.BunifuFlatButton_MouseClick(Object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.OnMouseClick(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Label.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at Project.Program.Main() in C:\Project\Project\Program.cs:line 19
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile, Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yeah currently there's an issue with [Bunifu Flat Button](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/#bunifu-flat-button-2). You can however use (as I have always done in such design use-cases) a [Bunifu Thin Button](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/#bunifu-thin-button-2) or even better, a [Bunifu Image Button](https://devtools.bunifu.co.ke/bunifu-ui-winforms-docs/#bunifu-image-button) if you'd wish to set an "Exit" button with an image only.

Comment: Why is that? Tried to find any documentation regarding that behaviour (the links you provided are no longer available), but didn't find anything useful... I'm having the same issue as the OP, and the thing here is, that I do the same thing on other forms of my application (after finishing an operation, closing it), but the issue happens only in one of them.

Answer (score 6):

I think that this happens because bunifu buttons have some methods like "change color on hover, color on mouse click etc" , 
when you click the button , the form closes, but then maybe the app tries to call a method on that bunifu button like for example change color after mouse click, but the form is closed, and then the error happens.

**I fixed this by disabling the button before form close:**

```
private void bunifuFlatButton1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    bunifuFlatButton1.Enabled = false;
    this.Close();
}
```